# Spark utf 8 error, non-English data becomes `??????????`

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

One of the fields in our data is in a non-English language (Thai). 
We can load the data into HDFS and the system displays the non-English field correctly when we run:

`hadoop fs -cat /datafile.txt`

However, when we use Spark to load and display the data, all the non-English data shows `??????????????`

We have added the following when we run Spark:

```
System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8")
```

Has anyone else seen this? What do I need to do to use non-English data in Spark?

We are running Spark 1.3.0, Scala 2.10.4 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Command that we run to test is:

```
val textFile = sc.textFile(inputFileName)
textFile.take(10).foreach(println)
```

Comment: When you say "use Spark", what exactly are you doing? Also what are your locale settings (output of `locale`), and what encoding is your data in (check the bytes).

Comment: @lmm I checked and found that none of the locales were registered at all. I have to register `th_TH.UTF-8` manually. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are running Spark on Docker and the problem was to do with setting the `locale`.

To set the `locale` on Docker, you need to `update-locale` then use `source /etc/default/locale`. Restarting Docker will not do this for you.

Thanks @lmm for the inspiration.

Comment: This link about docker and locale also helps http://jaredmarkell.com/docker-and-locales/